# Xcode - defining a preprocessor macro for conditional compilation

Tags: xcode, macros, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'm using XCode 4, and in my project build settings, I've set :

```
Preprocessor macros
   Debug   DEBUG;FULL
   Release FULL
```

and in another target of the same project :

```
Preprocessor macros
   Debug   DEBUG;LITE
   Release LITE
```

The two targets are using exactly the same files, except the plist info file that is made distinct.

Then later in my code, I wrote :

```
#ifdef FULL
    // ###### FULL VERSION
    NSLog(@"test");
    // ###### 
#endif
```

But the log is never written.

What am I doing wrong ?
I don't want (need) to set a value to the FULL statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiple preprocessor macros are separated by spaces not semicolon. So it should be:

```
Preprocessor macros
   Debug   DEBUG FULL
   Release FULL
```

With the semicolon, you're defining a single macro called "DEBUG;FULL". And that won't match your `#ifdef`.